# Could I get help finding the output of this function? (C++)

Tags: c++, char, c-strings, strlen

What would the output of this code be, with all of the appropriate includes?

I understand what everything does up until `*(x+4) = x[n];`, and from there I got a little lost.

```
int main(){
    int n;
    char y[10] = "tasked";
    char *x = y;
    n = strlen (x);
    *(x+4) = x[n];
    x++;
    printf ("%s",x);
}
```

Edit: I didn't understand what `*(x+4) = x[n];` did to the string, thank you all!

Comment: Why don't you run it?

Comment: Try running the code in an online C or C++ editor such as: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Comment: You have to _ask_ yourself.

Comment: Agree with all the other reviewers. You need to run it to get the answer. Should it have been the question about how to run the code?

Comment: Careful with "Just run it" advice. It falls down in the face of Undefined Behaviour. Fortunately I see none of that in this code, so running it works in this case, but how is someone who doesn't understand the code supposed to know that?.

Answer (score 3):

The output of the program will be

```
ask
```

After this declaration

```
char y[10] = "tasked";
```

the array y is initialized the following way

```
char y[10] = { 't', 'a', 's', 'k', 'e', 'd', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0' };
```

That is all characters that do not have a corresponding initializing character from the string literal are zero-initialized.

After this statement

```
n = strlen (x);
```

n is equal to 6.

So this statement

```
*(x+4) = x[n];
```

do the following. It substitutes the character 'e' (at index 4) for the character '\0' (at index 6);

So after that the array has the following content

```
{ 't', 'a', 's', 'k', '\0', 'd', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0' }
```

Then the pointer advances one position and points to the second character of the array (with index 1) that is to the character 'a'.

So starting from this character 'a' until the terminating zero is encountered the characters 'a', 's', and 'k' are outputted.

Comment: Other than I'm pretty sure `*(x+4) = x[n];` is UB  (since "tasked" is actually a const char)

Comment: @UKMonkey You are wrong. It is a well-formed code. The both addressed characters of the array are initialized.

Comment: Yeah - just noticed that it's an array (which would be a copy) rather than pointer - my mistake

Comment: I think I understand most of what the function does, except for what `*(x+4) = x[n];` does.

Comment: @JoshRinehart See my uodated post. *(x+4) = x[n]; is the same as x[4] = x[n]; that is x[4] = x[6]; Or the same as *( x + 4 ) = *( x + 6 ).

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Open this [site](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_debugger) : and paste your code, then add the following before the "int main()" line:

```
#include <string.h>
```

This will allow you to use the "strlen" function.
Click the green "Run" button to get the output.
Then follow @Vlad from Moscow's answer and you will be informed.